# Actualizar valor dentro de un Foreach

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, foreach

por favor ayúdenme, necesito actualizar el resultado de mi total cada ves que modifique la cantidad

```
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    function operacion(field) {
                                        //Obtengo el formulario
                                        var form = field.parentNode; 
                                        //Obtengo el valor del campo 1
                                        var numero1 = form.cantidad.value; 
                                        //Obtengo el valor del campo 2          
                                        var numero2 = form.precio.value;
                                        //Hago el calculo y se lo asigno al campo de texto correspondiente          
                                        form.total.value = ( numero1 * numero2 );                                                                              
                                        console.log(form.total.value);
                                    }    
                                </script>
<?php
    $totalProducto=0;
    foreach ($sql_Producto as $itemListarProductoCarrito):
    $preci = $itemListarProductoCarrito['costo_promedio_producto'];
?>
<form>
     <table  class="table table-bordered">                                                                   
      <tr>
      <a href="eliminardelcarro.php?id=<?php echo $c["product_id"]; ?>" class="fa fa-fw fa-minus-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar"></a>
    </tr>                                                                                                                          
    <tr><br>
    <!--aqui le aumento para la cantidad para poder modificar si el ususario lo desea-->
    <label>Cantidad</label>
    <select name="cantidad" style="width:100px;" class="form-control" onchange="operacion(this)" >
        <option value="<?php echo $c["q"]; ?>"><?php echo $c["q"]; ?></option>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>                                                                        
    </tr> 
    <tr><br>
    <td><label>Precio Unitario</label></td>
    <td><input align="right" style="width:100px;" class="form-control" type="text" name="precio" value="<?php echo $preci;/*recibo mi precio*/ ?>"  onchange="operacion(this)"  readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Total</label></td>
        <td><input align="right" style="width:100px;" class="form-control" type="text" name="total" value="<?php echo '$' . $total = $c["q"] * $preci; /*aqui multiplico la cantidad enviada * por el precio*/?>"readonly></td>
        <?php $totalProducto += $total;/*sumo todos los valores totales*/ ?>
    </tr>
</table>

     </form>
 <?php
 endforeach;
?>
```

hasta qui todo funciona bien ya que me suma todos los valores dentro de mi foreach Ahora nesecito igual sumar los valores pero ahora estos con un SELECT para cambiar la cantidad ya que la cantidad $c["q"] me envia de otro formulario pero ya no puedo con la nueva cantidad ya que estaria conteniendole con el name="total" creo seria de hacerle algo pero no se me ocurre como

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pon la función que estás usando en el onchange

Comment: Esa función sola la ocupo para multiplicar la cantidad con el precio ya la edito y le subo la función Listo